# Using threads within a scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to use multiple threads within a scrapy spider? For example lets say i have built a spider which crawl blog topics and saves all the messages within. I would like to couple every topic to a thread from a pool, and the thread will crawl all the needed information. Each thread will crawl a different topic that way..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scrapy itself is single-threaded, and resultantly you ***cannot*** use multiple threads within a spider. You can however, make use of multiple spiders at the same time (`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`), which may help you (*[see Common Practices](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html)*)

Scrapy does not use multithreading as it is built on [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation), which is an  asynchronous http framework.

Comment: If I create a python thread pool within the spider code, why does it not able to support the threads?

Comment: @Eran Because the underlying framework of the spider code is asynchronous,

Answer (score 12):

The marked answer is not 100% correct.

Scrapy runs on twisted and it supports returning deferreds from the pipeline `process_item` method.

This means you can create a deferred in the pipeline as for example from `threads.deferToThread`. This will run your CPU bound code inside the reactor thread pool. Be careful to make correct use of `callFromThread` where appropriate. I use a semaphore to avoid exhausting all threads from the thread pool, but setting good values for the settings mentioned below might also work.

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/core/howto/threading.html

Here a method from one of my Item pipelines:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    def handle_error(item):
        raise DropItem("error processing %s", item)

    d = self.sem.run(threads.deferToThread, self.do_cpu_intense_work, item)
    d.addCallback(lambda _: item)
    d.addErrback(lambda _: handle_error(item))
    return d
```

You may want to keep an eye on

`REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE` as described here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#reactor-threadpool-maxsize

`CONCURRENT_ITEMS` as described here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-items

You are still facing the Python GIL though, which means CPU intense tasks will not really run in parallel on multiple CPUs anyway, they will just pretend to do that. The GIL is only released for IO. But You can use this method to use an IO blocking 3rd party lib (e.g. webservice calls) inside your item pipeline without blocking the reactor thread.

Comment: Still a great answer! Thx.

Comment: @GregorMelhorn: Why does one need to use `DeferredSemaphore` to "limit" the amount of work done in Twisted threadpool? Wouldn't scrapy's `CONCURRENT_ITEMS` setting take care of it?

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni as it is already written in my post: These settings might also work, I used the semaphore to be absolutely sure I don't run out of threads. In any case you need to use deferToThread.

Comment: @GregorMelhorn: How do you keep track of total resources used in scrapy using Twisted `DeferredSemaphore`? Do you keep one globally? One per item pipeline? One per spider?

Comment: I don't remember, this was 6 years ago :) but regarding semaphore VS concurrent items:  suppose the semaphore is necessary because if your thread takes longer than the scrapy item, there might be a lot more threads running than there are items concurrently in the pipeline. I am not sure how this is counted from scrapy - better double check.