# Scrapy item processing blocking new requests in broad crawl

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently building a Scrapy script that performs a broad crawl with the following settings:

```
'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 600,
'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 25,
'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 250,
'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE': 600,
```

To perform the broad crawl I loop through a list of domains here in my spider like this:

```
    def start_requests(self):
        for domain in self.domains:
            yield scrapy.Request("https://www." + domain['domain'], self.parse, meta={'domain':domain})
```

The loop works well, making more than 10 calls per second.

I noticed however that my entire **scraping** slows down as soon as I send my first items to be processed in my pipeline (which performs simple loops and conditional checks).

The issue seem to be that the loop in start_requests() waits for currently processed items to finish, before continuing my broad crawl for new domains, and this despite being way below my 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' limit.

Result is a script that runs 2 to 3x slower.

Isn't the item processing supposed to not block the requests?

Answer (score 1):

[Scrapy uses concurrency, not multi-threading](http://krondo.com/in-which-we-begin-at-the-beginning/).

Network input and output (requests sent and responses received) do not block your code, but never will two parts of your code be executed at the same time.

Scrapy uses Twisted, and if you cannot make your code more efficient you may be able to make your pipeline code run in a separate thread [the Twisted way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34140412/939364).

Comment: Thanks a lot Gallaecio.
Will try today and keep you updated in this thread.

Comment: On the answer you linked to: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34140412/939364) 
I'm actually having hard time figuring out how to define the *self.sem* variable in the line
`d = self.sem.run(threads.deferToThread, self.do_cpu_intense_work, item)`

I've tried setting `self.semaphore = Semaphore(10)` in _init_ but I get the error

AttributeError: 'Semaphore' object has no attribute 'run' when doing `d = self.sem.run(...)` in the process_item() function.

Would you have any idea?